# How to check owner and licences of an Appstore application?

Tags: mac-appstore, apple-id, pages, keynote, license

How to check owner of an Appstore application? And licences used for downloading it.

My problem is the following:

1.A few years ago I installed Numbers, Pages and Keynote on a computer **WorkComp** using licence, which my company gave me. I used Apple id  **AppleID1** there.

2. I now have bought a new computer **MyComp** and connected the  **AppleID1**. to my main Admin  account (Admin1). I also still use the **AppleID1** on my work company computer **WorkComp**.
3. The new computer **MyComp** came with these apps pre-installed as they are free with new purchases. Now on **MyComp** the system asked me to update these applications and Prompted me to agree for it to transfer the pre-installed apps licence to the **AppleID1**. I agreed.
4. I then realised that now I am using the same Apple-id **AppleID1**. to licence the apps on both Macs and there may be a problems later. I wanted to get rid of the connection between the **AppleID1** licence on these applications on my computer **MyComp** (they suppose to be free anyway).
5. I created a new account on the **MyComp** (Admin2) and a new apple-id **AppleID2**. 
   But I saw that the applications are already installed and can be used by me. Nevertheless I tried to uninstall them and them download from Appstore again using AppleID2. And now I am not sure whether it worked or not, since everything looks exactly the same, and I  know that applications on my computer can be installed using different AppleIDs, and I have no way to check to which appleID and to which licence they belong too.

---

Also a little bit different question - may be it is possible to still use AppleID1, but somehow clear the licence for the applications and download them as a private user, who just bought a computer and can get them for free?

Comment: I delete my answer as it was not really helping. If it is the computer registering itself to the app store the entitlement for the apps. Then this would explain why you can see it in Purchases for both accounts rather than the 1 apple account. I would suggest you call Apple support bring to there attention you new purchase of a mac and explain that you accidentally agreed with the wrong account and this will be a problem.

Comment: Dont know what version OS your running, but there might be an adoption file that the app store creates.  /Library/Application\ Support/App\ Store/adoption.plist   That list apple apps and the id tied to them.  Check if it exists on your os.

Comment: @tron_jones, it is there, thank you. And though i reinstalled Pages applications with AppleID2 the file still tells about AppleID1, also there is a key and number, but i don't know what they means.

Comment: Exit out the App store, then delete that adoption.plist and restart App Store.  See if its the same.

Comment: @tron_jones, now the file is practically empty, there is one entry about "eligibilityRead" and I can find nothing about Pages.

Comment: Strange, As long as you don't have user data stored in the Apple applications, you can delete the app and re-install from app store under AppleID2, this would ensure that its now under the new apple ID